# GRPC not setting some headers

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I have this code to disable client caching for a GET API:

```
headers := metadata.Pairs(
    "Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
    "Pragma", "no-cache",
    "Expires", "0",
)
err := grpc.SetHeader(ctx, headers)
```

When I `curl -i` the API, the response shows `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate`, but not the Pragma or Expires. I think I'm using the right way to set these. Does GRPC not support certain headers?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any headers limitations (even though maybe problem can be with Pragma, which is HTTP 1.0, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Pragma). Maybe it's one of these reasons:

1. you only setHeader, but don't send it, see https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc?tab=doc#SetHeader

> All the metadata will be sent out when one of the following happens:
>
> - grpc.SendHeader() is called;
> - The first response is sent out;
> - An RPC status is sent out (error or success).

2. maybe `curl` is missused here, you don't seem to specify `--http2` option (see [Will I be able to use CURL to get HTTP/2 headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703642/will-i-be-able-to-use-curl-to-get-http-2-headers)), maybe you could leverage `grpcurl`: https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl